# checking the return value of a command executed using CreateProcess

Tags: windows

I am using the following code to execute 'taskkill' command using CreateProcess() api.

```
STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
si.cb = sizeof(si);
ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );

TCHAR cmd[] = TEXT("taskkill /F /T /IM <exe name>");

if (CreateProcess(NULL, cmd, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, & pi))
{
    // wait for child process to exit
    DWORD waitForStatus = WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, 10000);

    // close process and thread handles
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);

    /* code to throw exception based on the return value waitForStatus */ 
}
else
{
   /* code to throw exception if CreateProcess() failed */
}
```

What I observed is that if the process is not running, task kill fails, but CrateProcess() does not indicate the error. How to get this error from CreateProcess?

Is there any possibilty that the process does not get killed by taskkill even with the /F switch?

Answer (score 5):

***CreateProcess* is only responsible for spawning / creating the sub-process** (in your case *taskkill.exe*) which is successful, therefore it returns *TRUE*.
It's your code's responsibility to monitor the sub-process and when it ends to get its exit code. Do that by calling [[MS.Learn]: GetExitCodeProcess function (processthreadsapi.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getexitcodeprocess) before closing its handle:

```c
// ...

DWORD ec;

// ...

GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess, &ec);
```

Reverse the order of handle closing (it's not mandatory, but logically a thread ends before its process).

Comment: the sequence of closing handles, i saw it in the msdn link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682512(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: The order in which you close the handles doesn't matter - they belong to your process, and they don't affect the child process in any way.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that, I mentioned it... it's just a syntactically sugar... the thread is destroyed before the process(in the code)