# How to get the returned exit value of an invoked program to store it internally?

Tags: c++, winapi, process, exit-code

This question is related to a previously asked question found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63256524/1757805):

I'm able to invoke another executable within my `runProgram()` function. However, before this `runProgram()` function returns back to `main()` and closes the handle for the process. I need to retrieve the value that the executable returns when it exits...

Here is my current application:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <exception>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

uint32_t runProgram(LPCSTR lpApplicationName) {
    STARTUPINFOA si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    // Set the size of the structures
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    // Run the program
    CreateProcessA(
        lpApplicationName,  // the path
        NULL,               // Command line
        NULL,               // Process handle not inheritable
        NULL,               // Thread handle not inheritable
        FALSE,              // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
        CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, // Opens file in seperate console
        NULL,               // Use parent's environment block
        NULL,               // Use parent's starting directory
        &si,                // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
        &pi                 // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
    );

    uint32_t error = GetLastError();

    if ( error != 0)
        std::cerr << error << "\n";

    // How to retrieve and store the result from the exiting program above...?
    uint32_t cache_size = 0;

    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);

    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);

    return cache_size;
}

int main() {
    try {
        const uint32_t cache_size = runProgram("CacheQuerry.exe");
        std::cout << cache_size << '\n';
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << "\n\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

And I want to store the return value from this executable into `runProgram()`'s local variable: `cache_size`.

Here is the main.cpp from the invoked program:

```
#include "CacheQuerry.h"

int main() {
    int error = cache_info();
    if (error != 0)
        std::cout << error << '\n';
    else
        std::cout << '\n';
    std::cout << "l1d_cache_size = " << l1d_cache_size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "cache line size = " << cache_line_size() << '\n';
    return l1d_cache_size();
}
```

The invoked program will return the value produced by `l1d_cache_size()` when this program exits. This is the value that I want to store within `runProgram()`'s `cache_size` variable. How do I get this return value after the program exits? The implementation of the function call found in `"CacheQuerry.h"` shouldn't be relevant here, but if you need to see it's implementation don't hesitate to ask. These are two separate projects within the same solution. The 1st main.cpp which is in its own project relies on the 2nd main.cpp within its own project.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30612990/440558

Comment: Calling `GetLastError()` if `CreateProcessA()` DOES NOT return `FALSE` will return an *indeterminate value*. You can't do error handling with the Win32 API this way.  You have to check the return value of `CreateProcessA()` itself FIRST, *then* call `GetLastError()` only if valid to do so. And calling `WaitForSingleObject()` and `CloseHandle()` if `CreateProcessA()` actually fails is absolutely the wrong thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it by calling [`GetExitCodeProcess (pi.hProcess)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getexitcodeprocess), after waiting on the handle but before you close it.

The exact code you need is:

```
DWORD exit_code;
BOOL ok = GetExitCodeProcess (pi.hProcess, &exit_code);
```

Strange this is not mentioned in the Remarks section for `CreateProcess` at all.

Comment: Okay, but the function you are suggesting doesn't take 1 argument... It also requires a second: a `lpExitCode` and I'm not sure what to set this too..

Comment: Added the code you need.

Comment: Okay I had to create a temporary `DWORD ec` variable and passed that in my reference to the `GetExitCodeProcess()` function, however, I'm getting a value of `1` stored in my variable and I'm expecting it to be `64` as this is what the program returns...

Comment: Is `GetExitCodeProcess` succeeding?

Comment: Okay, I think I see what I'm doing wrong... I should be assigning my temp variable to the exit code, not from the return of this function...

Comment: Nope, when I return the `ec` I'm getting a value of `259`... It should be `64`

Comment: Are you calling `GetExitCodeProcess` _**after**_ waiting on `pi.hProcess`?  Code 259 means 'process still running', IIRC.

Comment: Okay I think I see what you are getting at... I have to call that after `WaitForSingleObject()` and not before it... I can try that...

Comment: And I made a mistake on my expected output... It was supposed to be 32 as in 32Kb for the l1 cache size, 64 is the cache line size... but It appears to be working now!

Comment: Nice I'm able to retrieve values from one executable and import them into another!

Comment: @FrancisCugler note that there are many ways to do that, exit codes are not the only way. Those are good for integers only, but maybe some day you want to return strings instead, or even binary data. Exit codes won't work for those.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I understand that, but for this particular use case and application, the values returned and needed will only ever be integers...

Comment: @FrancisCugler in that case, make sure you pay attention to the warning in the [`GetExitCodeProcess()` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getexitcodeprocess) when choosing what kind of integer values to return.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Those remarks are moot if you wait on the handle first.

Comment: @PaulSanders "*...if you wait on the handle...*" - I agree that is the *preferred* way to go, but a lot of people still don't actually do that. I've seen plenty of code where people run `GetExitCodeProcess()` in a loop waiting for the exit code to change from `STILL_ACTIVE` to something else (my own company has been caught doing that in the past).